# R freezes when loading the package 'clusterSim' with OS x El Capitan

Tags: r, osx-elcapitan

When I try to load the package clusterSim, R freezes without any output. I'm new to R and I don't know how to deal with this issue. I did not find any help in forums or other documentation.

SessionInfo() in R provides the following output:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.3 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base
```

I've tried this in the following ways always with the same outcome:

- From the R console with the package installer and from the command line.
- From the Terminal
- From R-Studio with the GUI and the Console.

I've tried as well to remove and reinstall R, R-Studio, The package 'clusterSim' and it's dependencies 'cluster' and 'MASS'.

When trying to install the package 'clusterSim' from source, the following output is generated, before the it freezes:

```
> install.packages('clusterSim', type='source')
Installing package into ‘/Users/marc/Library/R/3.2/library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://ftp.cixug.es/CRAN/src/contrib/clusterSim_0.44-2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4155487 bytes (4.0 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 4.0 MB

* installing *source* package ‘clusterSim’ ...
** package ‘clusterSim’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
clang++ -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include/freetype2 -I/opt/X11/include    -fPIC  -Wall -mtune=core2 -g -O2  -c clusterSim.cpp -o clusterSim.o
clusterSim.cpp:31:19: warning: unused variable 'b' [-Wunused-variable]
double l1,m1,m2,a,b;
                  ^
1 warning generated.
clang++ -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o clusterSim.so clusterSim.o -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
installing to /Users/marc/Library/R/3.2/library/clusterSim/libs
** R
** data
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
```

Can anyone help me to get this package loaded? It might be already useful if I knew how to get some more output when executing the command to load the package.

Thanks,

Marc

Comment: A more accurate word for "load" in your case is "install" as you are trying to install the package. Have you tried removing the folder that the message suggests? `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/00LOCK-clusterSim`

Comment: I can install the package using binaries. The problem is, that I can't load it when I need it in a session with `library('clusterSim')`. Deleting the folder helped to get the installation with the `type='source'` option further along to the point, where it freezes. I edited the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

A classmate found a solution:

Install https://www.xquartz.org and then restart R and then R does not freeze when you load clustermsim.

give it a go, it does work.